# NSFetchedResultsController and multiple relationships

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a UITableView which displays historical data. This is broken up into one section per day. Each day can have multiple things happening (eg. during a certain day I slept, ate some food, did some exercise, etc). Each "thing" is represented by a different entity. So going off the previous example, I have Day, Sleep, Food and Exercise entities. Sleep, Food and Exercise all have the Day entity as a parent, through a one-to-many relationship.

Currently what I am doing is loading all the Day entities, then for each Day I will load the Sleep, Food and Exercise entities into one single array, and sort it by date. Needless to say this gets slow when there is a lot of data.

Is it possible to use a NSFetchedResultsController in this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess, but I think the following would work:

EDIT - I have just verified with a simple case, that this does work

Have all of your event entities (Sleep, Food, Exercise) inherit from a base class entity (you could call it something like "Event") and then use the following when you are setting up your NSFetchRequest that your NSFetchedResultsController will use:

```
NSFetchRequest *fr = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[fr setEntity:entity];
```

In theory, this would cause your results controller to return all of your existing entities that inherit from *Event*.  You could also put the relationship to *Day* in the base class (Event) because all your subclasses have that in common.  Also, you would need to specify a predicate for your fetch request to only grab the events for the specific Day you are after.

Let me know if this works!